# Create a scoring formula to compare ratings

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, data-analysis

I have a table with 6 columns (name,1-5) representing rating number.
The table has rows with item name and how many 1 stars, 2 stars etc it received
For example:

```
Item    1   2   3   4   5
-------------------------
A       1   0   0   2   0
B       1   0   0   0   0
C       5   0   0   0   0
D       0   0   0   0   1
E       0   0   0   0   10
```

1. Now using just the naive *AVERAGE OF RATINGS* would result that D and E have same scores 5 however E is better because it has received more ratings than D so its just dumb to assign them same scores as E score should be higher.
2. Other issue is opposite of this i.e. C and B would have same score 1 however C is worse than B so score for C should be lower.

I tried to use weighted average rating which takes into account weights to measure quantity and quality

**Rating = (w1 * Average Rating Score) + (w2 * ln(Total Number of Ratings))**

*where:*

- w1 and w2 are weighting factors that you can adjust to reflect your preferences.

  - You can adjust the weighting factors to reflect your preferences for how much importance you want to give to the average rating score vs the number of ratings. For example, you may set w1=0.8 and w2=0.2 if you care more about the average rating score than the number of ratings.
- Average Rating Score is the mean of the 1 to 5 star ratings received by item .
- ln(Total Number of Ratings) is the natural logarithm of the total number of ratings received by the item. Taking the logarithm helps to diminish the impact of large numbers of ratings, which could otherwise overwhelm the impact of the average rating score.

This method doesn't take into consideration of issue 2. which is that if we have more 1 star it gives me better rating for the item instead it should give less.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be more of a math or strategy problem than Excel. This is one suggestion.

[image]

Top row shows weightage assigned respectively to each category. Formula in cell G3 (copied down) is:

`=SUMPRODUCT(B3:F3,$B$1:$F$1)`

Comment: what is the reasoning behind the top row weights? why is 3 having 0.1 and can there be any drawbacks for it?

Comment: @pgs0001 You have to test it on your data if it is leading to correct results. assigning 0 to Item 3 will then disregard count in the cell as the calculation but to distinguish it from others I have used 0.1 (it can be 0.01 for what it is worth). Logic is fairly simple category 1 is negative category and then it is moving towards average (3) and then 5 is the positive category which I inferred from your description.

Answer (score 0):

@pgs0001 This may solve both issues

Item.i.rating = ARS * (1 + K * ln(NR.i))

K is an arbitrary weight to value the impact of the number of ratings (K>0)

Average Rating Score: ARS = (score1 * n1 + score2 *n2 +...+ scoreX *n x)/(n1 + n2 +...+ nx)

ln : natural logarithm

NR.i : number of ratings for item “i”

The rating scale must be symmetrical with a middle 0 value, e.g. -2,-1,0,1,2